# 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators, election

The 2013 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Has it been a year already?  Wow!

Comment: @LarianLeQuella: I was hoping you'd have kept your nomination in there; maybe you could get [two diamonds](http://mathoverflow.net/users/1/anton-geraschenko) if you won ;-)

Comment: Wait, you have to nominate yourself? I thought someone else could step up and ask you to run?

Comment: @RobZ No, moderator candidates are those who volunteer.  We need moderators who are not only qualified, but who are willing to put in the time and effort.  Someone can ask you to run, but if you aren't willing, you shouldn't be a candidate.

Comment: The election is confusing. There are currently 4 mods. The election is for *3* mods. None of the existing mods have (yet?) nominated. Normally, they wouldn't need to rerun for election. Are we replacing them (Sklivvz aside) or adding to them?

Comment: Adding to them, @Oddthinking. Existing mods need not run.

Answer (score 15):

Skeptics,

I need to make a quick announcement.

Part of the reason that this election is taking place is that I have "ascended" and accepted a position as a Core Developer here at Stack Exchange, inc. As you may have noticed I'm already at work <strike>in the bug mines</strike> closing bugs on meta.so.

So basically this leaves one community moderator spot open for election as, while I will not lose my diamond, I will be less involved in the day-to-day running of the site, obviously.

The *official* announcement of this is yet to come, but I thought it would be sensible to give you all the info you need in order to make your electoral decisions.

Please join me in wishing good luck to all candidates!

Comment: Congratulations, and thanks for all of your hard work (both past and future)!

Comment: Grats!  Well deserved!

Comment: Congrats! Now, get to work on [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178438+is%3Aquestion+%5Bfeature-request%5D+-%5Bstatus*%5D) ;-)

Comment: Congratulations old friend.  That is some good news indeed.

Comment: Very Congratulations. I'm sure you will make a excellent work there as well as you have done here!