# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Skeptics's [second moderator election](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the three new moderators are:

[image: Oddthinking] [image: Borror0] [image: Jamiec]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/1181062/0).

Also join me in thanking veteran moderator [Sklivvz](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/96) for his service [as he steps down after two years](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/2013-community-moderator-election/2175#2175). Sklivvz was first [appointed as a Moderator Pro Tempore](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/moderator-pro-tem-announcement?rq=1), and did such a great job that y'all elected him a year later when the site launched. Please wish him all the best in his new job here at Stack Exchange!

Comment: Congratulations to all three, and a warm welcome back to Borror0 and Oddthinking!

Comment: My <del>deepest condolescences</del> warmest congratulations to the new moderators. Well done!

Comment: Congratulations to all three and especially to Oddthinking who has always made a supergreat work here whitout being a moderator. He has always helped me to improve my great questions and I hope he continue to help all the people to post great questions and answers. Special congratulations to Sklivvz for his new job: surely we will have nostalgia of lacking a so great moderator.

Comment: Congratulations folks - happy to see the result!

Comment: Well done guys. I expect you will continue the good work and hope the effort required doesn't overwhelm you!

Comment: Congratulations All.  And I do hope Borror0 will invent a method for using that 20-sided die on his avatar to make decisions, so that Luck or some other Higher Power can play a role in moderation :-)

Answer (score 7):

Wow, I totally didn't expect that. Thank you very much to everyone who voted for me. I will do my best to keep this place as great as it already is.

Im <strike>literally</strike> figuratively shocked.

Comment: *Now you've done it!* Congratulations!